# False Nearest Neighbors in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe that contains multivariate time-series data. One column represents *temperature*, one column represents *humidity*, and one column represents *wind*. For example, a dataframe like below:

```
       temperature    humidity    wind
0           59           97        8
1           59           89        8
2           58           79        7
3           58           74        7
4           60           74        7
5           62           76        10
```

Then I want to apply **takens embedding (time delay embedding)** algorithm on this dataframe. I use *Giotto-TDA* package to apply takens embedding on the dataframe. The link below shows how this package performs takens embedding on data:
https://giotto-ai.github.io/gtda-docs/latest/modules/generated/time_series/embedding/gtda.time_series.TakensEmbedding.html

Takens Embedding Algorithm takes two inputs that are *time_delay* and *dimension*. If we have a univariate time-series, we can perform a heuristic function on time-series data to find the optimal *time_delay* and *dimension* for takens embedding algorithm. The heuristic function is available in the link below:
https://giotto-ai.github.io/gtda-docs/latest/modules/generated/time_series/embedding/gtda.time_series.takens_embedding_optimal_parameters.html#gtda.time_series.takens_embedding_optimal_parameters

But when we are working on multivariate time-series data, like my dataframe in above, we should use **false nearest neighbors** algorithm to find optimal values for *time_delay* and *dimension*. But I have not found any available function in python to run false nearest neighbors on my dataframe. I have just found a package named TISEAN that can perform false nearest neighbors on time-series data. The links to *false nearest neighbors* algorithm in *TISEAN* package are:
https://www.pks.mpg.de/tisean/TISEAN_2.1/docs/chaospaper/node9.html
and
https://www.pks.mpg.de/tisean//TISEAN_2.1/docs/docs_c/false_nearest.html

But as you can see the package is not written in python and I think is written in C language.

I wanted to know how I can use TISEAN package in python to perform *false nearest neighbors* on my dataframe? or is there any other way in python except using *TISEAN* to perform the *false nearest neighbors* algorithm on my multivariate time-series data?

Answer (score 4):

A library called teaspoon has an implementation of the false nearest neighbours algorithm. It also has mutual info and takens embedding theorem. Here's the link:
https://lizliz.github.io/teaspoon/FNN.html

I do also believe someone wrote TISEAN on github in python. Here is another link:
https://github.com/galaunay/pytisean

If you want to use Cao's improved method of FNN, I used R in python, so if you have the required packages you can used this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri

nonlinearTseries = importr("nonlinearTseries")
data = numpy2ri.numpy2rpy(savgol_price)

cao_emb_dim = nonlinearTseries.estimateEmbeddingDim(
    data,  # time series
    len(data),  # number of points to use, use entire series
    62,  # time delay
    20,  # max no. of dimension
    0.95,  # threshold value
    0.1,  # max relative change
    True,  # do the plot
    "Computing the embedding dimension",  # main
    "dimension (d)",  # x_label
    "E1(d) & E2(d)",  # y_label
    ro.NULL,  # x_lim
    ro.NULL,  # y_lim
    1e-5  # add a small amount of noise to the original series to avoid the
          # appearance of false neighbours due to discretization errors.
          # This also prevents the method to fail with periodic signals, 0 for no noise
)

embedding_dimension = int(cao_emb_dim[0])
```